# Info that should be in the bug tracking system, ends up lost in emails somewhere. What To Do?

Tags: bug-tracking, email, issue-tracking

I am a developer with a small company which is about to take on a large project.

We currently use email for issue tracking, and I intend to set up a bug/issue tracking system 
*(perhaps bug genie, mantis or trac - we want something web based, php, open source, mysql)* 
We have source control (SVN)

In the past I have found that the biggest problem with bug tracking systems is that information is split between the tracking system and emails.

What do you do to make sure that information in emails is available to people reviewing bugs in your bug tracking software?

What do you do to make it easy for people working on bugs to make information in the emails they send and receive available to the bug tracking system? 

In my experiece if it isn't easy people will avoid doing it.

Comment: I f you search SO, there are quite a few posts on the subjrct of bug tracking for one man and small shops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use any of the systems you'd consider (no php;-), but, on systems I do use, emails sent in response to any email from the bug tracker go to the bug tracker itself (`reply-to` header) unless the responder does some very very explicit action to stop that; the bug tracker makes the email's contents one more comment on the bug, stores attachments as "uploaded files", and so forth. If none of the trackers you're considering have this functionality, I suggest you broaden your considerations to trackers that DO have it (whatever language they're implemented in, is less important than their functionality).

email is just too important, too useful, too widespread; systems such as issue trackers MUST be able to interoperate smoothly with email (incoming and outgoing) to be considered good.

Answer (score 8):

One of my favorite jokes goes like this:

> Patient:  "Doc, it hurts when I do
>   this".
>
> Doctor:  "Don't do that".

When you switch to bug-tracking software, inform everyone involved that you're no longer tracking bugs by email, and that any emails they send regarding bugs will be completely ignored.  Follow this up by ignoring any emails sent regarding bugs.

Comment: That's the best response I've seen to date on SO

Answer (score 1):

If you use a web based system with a public facing site for customers, you should eliminate using emails at all. In fact, if you have a good web based system, it should be easier for customers to use it rather than sending emails, so there should be little resistance to the change.

I have implemented [Gemini](http://www.countersoft.com/home.aspx) successfully at several shops. It's easy to use, very effective and free for up to 5 users. But since you are already using SVN, [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) would seem a natural choice.

Also see:

- [What bug tracking software do you use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328/what-bug-tracking-software-do-you-use)
- [Project tracking/management tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60240/project-trackingmanagement-tool)
- [What is your bug/task tracking tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101774/what-is-your-bug-task-tracking-tool)
- [Free/Cheap Task/Bug Management software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86394/freecheap-taskbug-management-software)

Answer (score 0):

Attach the e-mail(s) to the issues in your bug-tracking software.

Issues sometimes arise from e-mail conversations. So, save the e-mails in a suitable format (i.e. HTML or text), and add as an attachment to the new issue.

For clarity and convenience, it may be helpful to copy and paste pertinent bits of the e-mails into the issue.

Obviously, this also works if the issue already exists, and the e-mails follow. Rather than threatening to ignore future e-mails (other than as a last resort!), I'd suggest copying the text into the issue, and then replying to the e-mail, saying what you've done, and requesting that any future comments be added to the issue directly.